# networkx, moore-neighbourhood, shortest path issue

Tags: python, networkx, shortest-path

I am trying to build a rectangular graph in a Moore-neighbourhood. Within that, I am searching for the shortest path (`nx.shortest_path`) but get strange (zig-zag) [image: results].

I am quite sure, the reason for that is how i build the graph, but dont find the problem.

First, I build the Grid and the nodes:

```
#Building the Grid and the nodes
resolution = 1
length = 10
index = 0
xGrid = np.arange(0, length+1, resolution)
yGrid = np.arange(0, length+1, resolution)
G = nx.Graph()
print(xGrid)
meshNumber = np.zeros((length, length))
for i in range(length):
    for j in range(length):
        G.add_node(index, pos=(
            xGrid[j], yGrid[i]))
        meshNumber[j,i] = index
        index += 1
```

Then, i calcuate the edges and its weights

```
# Building the edges
diag = np.sqrt(2) * resolution
for i in range(1, length-2):
    for j in range(1, length-2):
        if meshNumber[j, i]:
            if meshNumber[j - 1, i]:
                G.add_edge(
                    meshNumber[j, i], meshNumber[j - 1, i], weight=resolution)
            if meshNumber[j + 1, i]:
                G.add_edge(
                    meshNumber[j, i], meshNumber[j + 1, i], weight=resolution)
            if meshNumber[j, i - 1]:
                G.add_edge(
                    meshNumber[j, i], meshNumber[j, i - 1], weight=resolution)
            if meshNumber[j, i + 1]:
                G.add_edge(
                    meshNumber[j, i], meshNumber[j, i + 1], weight=resolution)
            if meshNumber[j - 1, i - 1]:
                G.add_edge(
                    meshNumber[j, i], meshNumber[j - 1, i - 1], weight=diag)
            if meshNumber[j - 1, i + 1]:
                G.add_edge(
                    meshNumber[j, i], meshNumber[j - 1, i + 1], weight=diag)
            if meshNumber[j + 1, i + 1]:
                G.add_edge(
                    meshNumber[j, i], meshNumber[j + 1, i + 1], weight=diag)
            if meshNumber[j + 1, i - 1]:
                G.add_edge(
                    meshNumber[j, i], meshNumber[j + 1, i - 1], weight=diag)
```

searching for the path:

```
# Finding the path
start = 5
end = 66
try:
    path = set(nx.shortest_path(G, start, end))

except nx.exception.NetworkXNoPath:
    raise AssertionError("Could not find a good Path")
```

plotting:

```
# Plotting
flatten = np.ones((index), dtype=np.int)
for p in path:
    flatten[int(p)] = 900
flatten[start] = 1000
flatten[end] = 1000
colors = []
for f in flatten:
    colors.append(str(f))
pos = nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'pos')
fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(12, 12), dpi=90)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
pos = nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'pos')
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_color=colors, node_size=500, alpha=0.8,
                       linewidths=3)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, width=1.0, alpha=0.5)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, width=4, alpha=0.5, edge_color='#6985a5')
labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(G, 'weight')
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos, edge_labels=labels)
plt.savefig("zigzag.png")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That strange zigzag is a valid shortest path of 6 edges, I don't see what is the problem. On the other hand the zigzag is not the shortest path if we take into account the **weight** of the edges. For which case you must use:

```
try:
    path = set(nx.shortest_path(G, start, end, weight='weight'))

except nx.exception.NetworkXNoPath:
    raise AssertionError("Could not find a good Path")
```

Giving you the following path:
[image: new path]

Comment: ah - thx! your right; I was considering the weighted path. I didnt know that i have to explicitly input the weight in shortest_path.